# Inconsistent SUMPRODUCT return value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What the heck is going on here? Is this a bug?

In the example below, this formula is meant to count the number of apples that aren't made of plastic.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B4=IF(NOT($C$4:$C$11),$B$4:$B$11)))
```

It is supposed to return 1. Why is it returning 2?

[image]

When I manually evaluate the array inside `SUMPRODUCT` using <kbd>F9</kbd>, I can see there's only one 1 there; when I then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it returns 1, which is what I expected from the start.

[image]

[image]

The best part: If I copy the exact same original formula to other cells (not dragged -- it has the exact same cell references), then it returns 0 or a `#VALUE!` error. Why would the result change like that?

[image]

Test data for your copy-pasting pleasure:

```
Fruit   Made of plastic
apple   FALSE
banana  FALSE
plum    FALSE
pear    TRUE
apple   TRUE
banana  FALSE
plum    TRUE
pear    TRUE
```

Comment: Try, instead: `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$4:$B$11=B4)*($C$4:$C$11=FALSE)*1)`  I think you were just over complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `COUNTIFS` function instead, since you are trying to count based on multiple criteria:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B, B4, C:C, False)
```

Answer (score 1):

actually everything is alright in your formula. You just need to press **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>** to calculate the formula.
When you press **<kbd>enter</kbd>** **ONLY** then it doesn't take into account that the formula is array based. 
But when you evaluate the formula using **`F9`**
, it knows that the array is an array, so that is why you see the curly brackets in the evaluated formula, and then when you press **<kbd>enter</kbd>** only, since the array part is already calculated as an array using **`F9`**, then it retunrs **1**. 
But if you press <kbd>enter</kbd> from the beginning, without any evaluation, then it will return two! that is why.

 The same story when you copy your formula into another cell. There also, you need to press **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>** to calculate the array formula.

Comment: This does work... But I don't understand why. I thought `SUMPRODUCT` didn't need to be entered as an array formula, even when its arguments were arrays? Also not clear why this would cause the same formula to behave differently when entered in different cells.

Comment: To illustrate my point, see my [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29692404/119775), which doesn't need to be entered as an array formula. Incidentally, I have to avoid array formulas, because this formula is going to be used for conditional formatting — which doesn't accept array formulas.

Answer (score 1):

I have a theory - and it is no more than that (but won't fit in a comment) - that the underlying reason is the short-circuiting nature of IF.

Take the first `apple` - it is associated with FALSE so count 1. Is there another FALSE in the list? Yes, so is there another `apple` in the list? Also Yes, so add 1, result `2`.
Take the first `banana` - as above, result `2`.
Take the first `plum` - as above, result 2.
Take the first `pear` - it is associated with TRUE, so count 0 – and stop counting.
Take the second `apple` - it is associated with TRUE, so count 0 - and stop counting.
Take the second `banana` - it is associated with FALSE, so count 1. Is there another FALSE in the list? Yes, so is there another `banana` in the list? Also Yes, so add 1, result `2`.
Take the second `plum` - it is associated with TRUE, so count 0 – and stop counting.
Take the second `pear` - it is associated with TRUE, so count 0 – and stop counting.

But this coupled with the *implied intercept* - it only works for B4 when in Row4.

> Is this a bug?

I think safe to say, not a bug.

> Why is it returning 2?

*Maybe* the above is the explanation (I have not tested it!)

> What the heck is going on here?

Perhaps not answerable in great detail without access to Microsoft's code?

Comment: What do you mean by *implied intercept*? Why would `IF` "stop counting" when it encounters a `TRUE`?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$4:$B$11=B4)*NOT($C$4:$C$11))
```

It does not need to be entered as an array formula.